# Close TKinter Gui on thread completion

Tags: python, multithreading, user-interface, tkinter, python-multithreading

I am working on a project where, basically there is 2 options

1. Manual filling  <---- works fine
2. Automatic filling <----- small problem here

So in manual fill, after finishing a small loop, i can kill the GUI as i dont need multi threading

In automatic, i use a seperate thread to overcome the not responding issue.

Now, after i finish the thread execution, i want to destroy root tk

But it tells to execute from main thread

Is there a way to create an event or any method of thread to tell root to close?

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre] and the full traceback if any.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Widgets in tk have methods `.after` and `.after_idle` that are threadsafe.  They take a callback function that runs in the main thread, so you can destroy the root window there.